# (discord.js) TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' when trying to send a direct message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was trying to use the following code to send a welcome message, but it seems that it can't read the property **'send'**
Here's the code:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId).send(`<@${member.id}> Welcome to the server!`)
})
```

Error message:

```
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId).send(`<@${member.id}> Welcome to the server!`)
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/index.js:25:54)
    at Client.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_ADD.js:16:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/Discord Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1137:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:520:28)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The channel might not be stored in the cache yet. You can do

```
member.guild.channels.fetch(welcomeChannelId).then(chan=> 
member.guild.channels
      .fetch(welcomeChannelId)
      .then((chan) => chan.send(`<@${member.id}> Welcome to the server!`))
      .catch(() => null);
```

Fetch will check if the channel is in the cache and if it isn't it will fetch it.

Comment: `.fetch()` doesn't return null or undefined if the channel is not found, it rejects the promise. You will have to use `.catch(() => null)` if you want it to work properly

Comment: The error message `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')` still appears. I guess there is a bug which makes it can't read the element `.send`?

Comment: i updated my original answer that should work.